# Can I reduce the space between radiobuttons in a radiogroup?

Tags: android, radio-group

This is my .xml file

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_medium">

    <com.google.android.material.radiobutton.MaterialRadioButton
        android:id="@+id/high_school_answer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/high_school"/>

    <com.google.android.material.radiobutton.MaterialRadioButton
        android:id="@+id/bachelor_answer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/bachelor"/>

    <com.google.android.material.radiobutton.MaterialRadioButton
        android:id="@+id/technical_answer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/technical"/>

    <com.google.android.material.radiobutton.MaterialRadioButton
        android:id="@+id/professional_answer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/professional"/>

</RadioGroup>
```

The below screenshot shows how it looks like

So I would like to reduce the vertical space between my radiobuttons.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I'm sure you can do this. I don't know how off the top of my head, though. You should look at the documentation global attributes available to all UI widgets. There should be something like `android:padding` or `android:margin`.

Comment: What's the orientation of your radiogroup? Vertical or horizontal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set height to RadioButton `android:layout_height="10dp"`

Comment: Great!... I set marginTop, it works but i think it isn't the best way because there is overlap, so, It's better if i do what you say. I think it looks cool with `android:layout_height="36dp"` Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting a vertical (top or bottom) `margin` to each of your RadioButtons. This would override the default margin that's already set. For instance, your code can look like this:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_medium">

    <com.google.android.material.radiobutton.MaterialRadioButton
        android:id="@+id/high_school_answer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:text="@string/high_school"/>

    <com.google.android.material.radiobutton.MaterialRadioButton
        android:id="@+id/bachelor_answer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:text="@string/bachelor"/>

    <com.google.android.material.radiobutton.MaterialRadioButton
        android:id="@+id/technical_answer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:text="@string/technical"/>

    <com.google.android.material.radiobutton.MaterialRadioButton
        android:id="@+id/professional_answer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:text="@string/professional"/>

</RadioGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set android:layout_marginTop="-8dp" with 2nd radiobutton onwards. It will reduce the vertical spacing between radiobuttons

Comment: Yes... That works. I thought there was an attribute to adjust the space between child views. But it works. Thank you so much!

Comment: But i think it's better if i set height instead marginTop, because there is overlap. However, thank you so much!!